# Where is the reference for functions available in CartoCSS

Tags: tilemill, cartocss

I'm playing with Tilemill and i see that for some properties, like marker-transform, i can use functions. I want to use rotate() which takes 3 arguments (i learned this by inputing just one so it reported an error). What i can't seem to find anywhere is the reference for these functions. Can someone point me to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check http://mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/upgrade/#transforms and http://mapbox.com/carto/api/2.1.0

`rotate()` and `scale()` are actually SVG transforms.